# cron_schedule table not emptying itself (deadlock error)

Tags: magento2, database, cron, magento-cron

I just realized after cheking my logs that all the queries supposed to clean my cron_schedule table are not being executed properly. My table just keeps on growing.

Here are the three exception types being thrown (several times each) :

```
[Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: DELETE FROM `cron_schedule` WHERE (status = 'missed') AND (job_code in ('ddg_automation_customer_subscriber_guest_sync', 'ddg_automation_importer', 'ddg_automation_status', 'ddg_automation_abandonedcarts', 'ddg_automation_reviews_and_wishlist', 'ddg_automation_campaign', 'ddg_automation_order_sync', 'ddg_automation_cleaner', 'ddg_automation_catalog_sync', 'ddg_automation_email_templates')) AND (created_at < '2019-11-27 03:30:08')  



[PDOException]                                                                                                   
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction  

cron:run [--group GROUP] [--bootstrap BOOTSTRAP]



[Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\DeadlockException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: DELETE FROM `cron_schedule` WHERE (status = 'missed') AND (job_code in ('ddg_automation_customer_subscriber_guest_sync', 'ddg_automation_importer', 'ddg_automation_status', 'ddg_automation_abandonedcarts', 'ddg_automation_reviews_and_wishlist', 'ddg_automation_campaign', 'ddg_automation_order_sync', 'ddg_automation_cleaner', 'ddg_automation_catalog_sync', 'ddg_automation_email_templates')) AND (created_at < '2019-11-27 04:18:02')
```

Can you help ?